# PrimeNG Date format from 11:53 to 11.53

Tags: angular, primeng

PrimeNg has `<p-calendar>`

You can set the dateformat for the calendar like so:

```
dateFormat="hh:mm"
```

In this case you can enter 11:53 and it would work.

However, I would like to enter 11.53 instead.

I tried this:

```
dateFormat="hh.mm"
```

If I enter 11.53, the entered value does not stay in the input box. Is it possible to use this kind of syntax ?

Comment: Looking at the documentation (https://www.primefaces.org/primeng-v14-lts/calendar) we see that the dateFormat only applies, as the name suggests, to dates and not to time.

Answer (score 0):

Following the [docs](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng-v14-lts/calendar) and the [playground](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-calendar-demo?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html), I guess you are not allowed to format time:

```
<p-calendar [(ngModel)]="date8" [timeOnly]="true" inputId="timeonly"></p-calendar>
```